# ¿Puedo cambiar el HTML a la hora de escribir un email en Gmail?

Tags: html, email, google-chrome

Necesito algo muy simples, quiero hacer un `<strike>` (tachado) en el texto de un email, p.ej.: <strike>tachado</strike>.

He encontrado la biblioteca [KartikTalwar/gmail.js: Gmail JavaScript API](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js), pero exige unas vueltas tremendas y la creación de una Extensión de Chrome para lograr algo semejante.

A veces uso los [snippets JS en el Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow) para manipular el DOM de las páginas, pero dudo que sea el camino:

[image: snippets en Dev Tools]

¿Alguna alternativa?

<sub><sup>*Cross-post en SOpt [É possível modificar o HTML na hora de escrever um email no Gmail?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111271/201). Texto original y traducción manual.*</sup></sub>

Comment: Estas tratando de enviar un email programáticamente o a través de la web?

Comment: Hola, Carlos, disculpa, tube un crash en el browser, la intención era publicar P&R a la vez

Comment: He borrado mis comentarios anteriores, nunca un -1 me había caído tan mal. Hasta llegué a borrar la pregunta, pero no me parece correcto después de todo mi trabajo. Duly noted, responde tu propia pregunta con texto original en SOes == get off.

Comment: Hola brasofilo, disculpa si un -1 te cae tan mal. El motivo por el que vote negativamente por la **pregunta** y vote por cerrar es que es offtopic. No trata sobre programación sino sobre el uso de Gmail, que es una aplicación web. Este tema ha sido votado como offtopic por la comunidad: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/162#162. Con respecto al voto negativo en la respuesta, disculpa, sí me excedí, no hay nada malo propio de la respuesta, necesito una edición en la respuesta para poder quitar mi voto negativo.

Comment: Che, Carlos, mi pregunta tiene un enlace a LA (mayúsculas) Biblioteca Gmail Open Source para usar en Extensiones Chrome. Hablo de Developer Tools. También de HTML y de herramientas que los programadores usan a diario.   Man, siento no haber preguntado sobre la OOP del Estornudo Atómico :(

Comment: Paso de cambiar nada. Si no reconoces un texto bien redactado de primera, no es mi problema

Comment: El texto está muy bien redactado, ese no es el problema mi estimado brasofilo. No deberías tener esa actitud simplemente entiende que la pregunta no trata sobre programación, que se puede usar código para resolver el problema tal vez pero no es el objetivo sino que el objetivo es acerca de una funcionalidad faltante en una aplicación web. Es mi opinión, otras personas pueden tener opiniones diferentes y todos tenemos derecho ha expresarnos, con comentarios y votos.

Comment: Tampoco me parece correcto que te expreses de forma tan negativa incluyendo en particular un comentario borrado que tuve que reportarlo por el lenguaje.

Comment: Si, lo hice sabiendo que iba a ser reportado. Me he sentido tan bienvenido como una mosca. Sitio para opiniones es el [meta], si te apetece redacta tú ahora una pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente, creo que la solución que propones es demasiado complicada para lo que quieres conseguir. Aquí voy a dejar dos alternativas más sencillas que incluso gente sin conocimientos técnicos puede usar:

## Opción 1: Usa plug-ins / extensiones en el navegador

En los diferentes navegadores puedes encontrar plugins y extensiones para añadir funcionalidad al editor de texto del correo de GMail. Como en la pregunta hablas de Chrome, voy a poner algunos ejemplos para ese navegador.

En el caso particular de tachar una frase (`strikethrough`), podrías usar la extensión [Strikethrough](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/strikethrough/peahilnfgiacdkackbnbdbgkkjaghool?hl=es), que hace precisamente eso: añadir un botón para poder tachar texto en el editor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero también puedes encontrar otros como [TeX for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-for-gmail/gjnmclkoadjdljnfmbnnhaahilafoeji?hl=es), [Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg?hl=es) o [Classic Gmail Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-gmail-compose/cbmmejeeogjpfmdlcdkolobdlohjkmjn?hl=es), por mencionar algunos en Chrome.

---

## Opción 2: Copia-pega desde un editor de texto

¿Para qué complicarse la vida con editar HTML o instalar plugins/extensiones? Aquí dejo un método supersimple que funciona incluso sin tener ningún tipo de conocimiento de HTML y sin saber cómo funcionan las extensiones.

Un método que hasta mi abuela sabría usar:

1. Escribe el email en tu editor de texto favorito (Microsoft Word, StarOffice, WordPad, Google Docs... no importa), incluso con opciones no disponibles en GMail: tachados, superíndices, subíndices, líneas horizontales, etc.
2. Copia el texto al editor de email de GMail
3. ¡Tachán! Ya está hecho

Comment: ¡Gracias mil, Alvaro! Dejaré esto abierto por ahora, pero creo que lo has clavado, *¿vamos hablar de "simples", estimado programador?  Pues aquí tienes herramientas simples a tu mano.*

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar directamente la manipulación del DOM en Developer Tools que ofrece tu navegador (browser). No es algo directo ni elegante como crear un botón extra para formatación, pero para alguién que programa HTML es algo **muy simples**:

- Pincha con el botón derecho justo arriba del texto que quieres cambiar y elige <kbd>Inspecionar Elemento</kbd><sub><sup>(Inspect Element)</sup></sub>.
- Ahora, encuentra el bloque de código correcto en el Dev Tools y de nuevo pincha con el botón derecho eligiendo <kbd>Editar como HTML</kbd><sub><sup>(Edit as HTML)</sup></sub>:

  [image: edit as html]
- Una vez ahí, cambia el código para `<strike>TU TEXTO</strike>` y...
  ¡lo tenemos!

  [image: webmail con strike]

<sup>PS: también sirve para otras tags HTML, como `<hr>`</sup>